# No matching handler method found - Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a JUnit Test:

```
@Autowired
private UserController userController;

@Test
public void getUser() throws Exception {
    User user = jUnitDAOHelper.createUser();

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    params.put("email", user.getUserDetail().getEmail());

    String result = sendRequest("/user", GET, userController, params);
    assertNotNull(result);
    System.out.println("result="+result);
}
```

This is my Controller (snippet):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController extends BaseController {
    // deleted
}
```

This is my sendRequest Method:

```
public String sendRequest(String url, String method, Object controller, Map<String, Object> params) throws Exception {
        request.setRequestURI(url);
        request.setParameters(params);
        request.setMethod(method);
        request.setContentType("application/json");
        handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
        return response.getContentAsString();
    }
```

Throwing this error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/user', method 'GET', parameters map['email' -> array<String>['test@test.com']]
```

HandlerAdapter:

```
    protected MockHttpServletRequest request;
    protected MockHttpServletResponse response;
    protected HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
       response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
       handlerAdapter = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerAdapter.class);
    }
```

Any ideas what's going wrong? I believe every thing is mapped correctly but it keeps throwing this.

Comment: Show us your `handlerAdapter`. I think you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: just because spring wires the objects, doen't mean the requestmapping is wired

Comment: could you show us the handler method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the method you are trying to call

```
handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
```

comes from the `HandlerAdapter` interface.

```
ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception;
```

I'm almost convinced you are using a **deprecated** `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` which when trying to `resolveHandlerMethod()` throws `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` if it doesn't find one.

Does your `UserController` `BaseController` have any handler methods? Doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote a controller class... but there's no actual *method* to handle the request! You need to write a method that takes arguments and produces a result.

Comment: i think he did... this is just a snippets as OP said

Comment: @PhilippSander Well, that error message says exactly that there isn't a correctly mapped method. If the method is there, it needs to be unsnipped!